# a programmatic way to add vertical and/or horizontal line to the chart?

Tags: vba, excel, charts, line

I wrote this up to showcase how to create 2 charts on the same worksheet programmatically.

http://blog.oppoin.com/cookbooks/buttons-forms-and-charts/lesson-25a-2-datasets-of-10-data-points-each-draw-2-graphs-in-2-charts/

I received a request from a student to show how I can also add a vertical or a horizontal line programmatically to the charts.

I googled around but I can only find manual ways as described by John Peltier.

Was wondering if there is a programmatical way to do this.

Comment: kimsia, i have taken the effort to answer your question. please let me know if anything is unclear about it or if it solved the issue rate it as the enswer. Thank you.

Comment: @K_B yes it is unclear. On the other hand, I have figured out exactly how to do it. Saying Series alone is honestly not enough. ChartType turns out to be very important. this is how to draw vertical line http://blog.oppoin.com/cookbooks/buttons-forms-and-charts/drawing-vertical-line-in-charts/ i have also figured out how to do it for horizontal line, but yet to write out the explanation in full.

Comment: You wrote, "It can be quite complicated, but also very simple, which depends on your current chart at hand and how fancy you want this to be." This line while true, does not help me answer my question. I prefer more useful answers like the explanation I have written. I think horizontal line is simpler than vertical line. Vertical line is definitely NOT simple IMO

Comment: i mention the chart types in my answer as well,  I assumed your programming level such that you would be helped with that. And it does depend on how you want it incorporated, as you ask a somewhat broad question a somewhat broad answer fits. Anyway good luck...

Comment: also looking at your code (a handful of lines to get the vertical line done) it is simple now isnt it, its not like a massively large script! For horizontal. Furthermore I do mention the chart types (in the first part) in my answer, and such you use...

Comment: i disagree with your points about it being simple and you mentioning charttypes (I used xlLine for horizontal line and a xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers for vertical line. I don't think you mentioned that at all.) Perhaps because you are better informed than me, so it may be the case of the curse of knowledge at work here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_knowledge In any case, thank you for your time to craft a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can manipulate a single `Series` object and its properties, thus you can give it a specific chart type thereby enabling you to add a line vertically (column diagram) or horizontally (same value for all X values, thick line chart type. or 2 stacked column series with the bottom one hidden).

So what you do is add a `Series` object to your `Chart` object and give it values and chart types so it shows as a line (horizontally or vertically).

It can be quite complicated, but also very simple, which depends on your current chart at hand and how fancy you want this to be.

PS: I see in your blog you don't declare your Subs Public or Private, which might be a good thing to do anyway...

Comment: In your blog you determine the min and max for the vertical line from the sheet content, an alternative is to use the min and max of the vertical axis instead (dblMinValue = Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale) also you can set the Axes' Scale min and max.